# How to completely ignore directories that until now I was tracking under version control using git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, directory, capistrano

I am using Ruby on Rails, the Capistrano gem and git. I would like to do not put anymore under version control some directories *that until now I was tracking*.

For my application I have a file system structure like the following:

```
...
.gitignore
/public/aaa/000/001
/public/aaa/000/002
/public/aaa/000/003
/public/aaa/000/...
```

To accomplish that I aim, I changed the `.gitignore` file and added to it the following lines:

```
# Ignoring "/public/aaa/*" directories
public/aaa/
```

However, *if I check what directories are under version control, I see that those I would like to ignore are still tracked*. So, when I deploy with Capistrano to the remote server the content of those directories is still changing.

**How can I definitely ignore those directories?**

---

In few words, what I would like to do is *to do not change `public/aaa` directories and files on the remote machine (and, thus, to do not track those with git on my local machine) so that when I deploy with Capistrano those folders (on the remote machine) are untouched*.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to remove them before they'll disappear from source control. They're still part of your git repo, so git is going to continue paying attention to them.

```
git rm -r --cached public/aaa
```

The `-r` tells git to remove the directory (just like `rm -r` in the console) and `--cached` tells git to leave the file(s), just remove it from the repo.

Comment: I made as you wrote, but it doesn't work. After deploying on the remote server all files and directories inside the 'public/aaa' folder have been removed\deleted (I have those files and directories only on my local machine)!!!

Comment: @karmajunkie It sounds like he want to stop tracking them, not remove them.

Comment: that's the DVCS equivalent of a code smell.  If you want them changed but don't want the changes tracked, don't change the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`.  This will keep the files around, but will no longer track their changes.

You can do this recursively with 
`find ./folder/ -type f | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged`

Comment: Please, (since I am new to git) can you be more explicit in the exposition and use of commands (maybe with an example including information that I provided in the question)?

Comment: This will keep the files in your repo, as they are now, but any changes to them won't be tracked.  For more info about the commands, check out the git man pages.  kernel.org is down now, but you can view the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Hs3zyuAuo6sJ:www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html+git+update-index&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: Referring to my inexperience with git, I still need an example (that considers information included in the question and) that recursively update the git index. I really so not understand the `find ./folder/ -type f | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged` part.

Comment: [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is a unix command. In this case, it acts as a pseudo recursive switch.  It takes the output of find and appends it to the command listed after xargs.  In your case replace './folder/' with './public/aaa/'

Comment: When I run that command I get the following error (I am running a Mac OS): `fatal: Unable to mark file public/aaa/.DS_Store`. *How can I solve that?*

Comment: I'm assuming it is because that file isn't in your repository, because it was hidden and never added.  Try  `find ./folder/ -type f -name '[!.]*' | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged`  This will ignore hidden files.

Comment: I do not know if it works because the console output is blank after I run the latter command that you provided.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3472/discussion-between-backo-and-andy)

Comment: Use 'find ./public/aaa/ -type f -name '[!.]*' | xargs -t git update-index --assume-unchanged` if you want to see the output, but it should be good if you didn't get any errors

Comment: It still doesn't work. After deploying the `public/aaa` still has changed on the remote machine.